# Extensionless URLs but keep Extension in the admin area

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, aspdotnetstorefront

I am using ASPDOTNETSTOREFRONT and we need to remove the extensions for the site but keep the extensions in the /admin folder so the back end will work correctly.  Below is what I have so far.

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Extensionless" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
                <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.aspx$" />
                <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.ashx$" />
            </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RemoveExtension" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)\.(aspx)$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```